# How to do a Speech Prompt Response

Tags: javascript, api, response, prompt, voice

How could you get the inputted text, in this example a name, to speak automatically what you've inserted as your name? So in this example code, having some enter their name, Harry Potter lets say, instead of text, the response would be verbal, "Hello Harry Potter, how are you today?"

I inserted an example audio code below the text input code as a particular point. 
If possible using the video

{name:"US English Female",flag:"us",gender:"f",voiceIDs:[39,
40,41,42,43,173,205,204,235,283,339,44]} rather than a drop down

I truly am terrible with javascript, so please only code no suggestions, because I will not know what they mean.

```
     <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>eve_</title>
<link rel="icon" rel="preload" href="images/evecircle.png" />


<style>

#video {
    margin-left:-10px;
    margin-top:-10px;



}

</style>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<style type="text/css">

body {
    overflow:hidden;
}

</style>

<body onload="delayedAlert();">

<script>
function myText() {
    var txt;
    var person = prompt("What's your name?", "");
    if (person == null || person == "") {
        txt = "User cancelled the prompt.";
    } else {
        txt = "Hello " + person + "! How are you today?";
    }
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = txt;
}

var timeoutID;

function delayedAlert() {
  timeoutID = window.setTimeout(slowAlert, 14999);
  then.getElementsByTagName('audiotwo')[0];
}

function slowAlert() {
 var audio= document.getElementsByTagName('audio')[0];
 const audio2 = document.getElementsByTagName('audio')[1];
 const audio3 = document.getElementsByTagName('audio')[2];


audio.play(); 
var myvar1;alert('...Hello?')

audio2.play();
var myvar2;alert('Hello?');

audio3.play();
var sign = prompt("What's your sign?");

if (person == null || person == "") {
  alert("Hello " + person + "! How are you today?");
}
}


</script>

 <audio>
  <source src="images/hellllloooo.wav" type="audio/wav" preload=true>
 </audio>

 <audio>
  <source src="images/sorry.wav?.wav?.wav" type="audio/wav" preload=true>
 </audio>

 <audio>
  <source src="images/sorry.wav?.wav?.wav" type="audio/wav" preload=true>
 </audio>






        <video autoplay="autoplay" preload="auto" id="video" src="images/secondnew.mp4" width="1300px" height="auto" style="position:absolute; z-index:-1;" >
        Video not supported.
         </video>






</body>
</html>
//////////////////////




  <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
    </head>
    JavaScript

    <script src="https://code.responsivevoice.org/responsivevoice.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>

    <textarea id="text" cols="45" rows="3">Hello world</textarea>

    <select id="voiceselection"></select> 

    <input 
      onclick="responsiveVoice.speak($('#text').val(),$('#voiceselection').val());" 
      type="button" 
      value="Play" 
    />

    <script>
            //Populate voice selection dropdown
            var voicelist = responsiveVoice.getVoices();
            var vselect = $("#voiceselection");
            $.each(voicelist, function() {
                    vselect.append($("<option />").val(this.name).text(this.name));
            });
    </script>

    <script src="https://code.responsivevoice.org/responsivevoice.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>

    <textarea id="text" cols="45" rows="3">What's your name?</textarea>

    <select id="voiceselection"></select> 

    <input 
      onclick="responsiveVoice.speak($('#text').val(),$('#voiceselection').val());" 
    />

    <script>
            //Populate voice selection dropdown
            var voicelist = responsiveVoice.getVoices();
            var vselect = $("#voiceselection");
            $.each(voicelist, function() {
                    vselect.append($("<option />").val(this.name).text(this.name));
            });
    </script>

    <body>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Like this:

```js
const name = prompt('What is your name?')
const sentence = 'Hello ' + name + '! How are you today?';
responsiveVoice.speak(sentence);
```

```html
<script src="https://code.responsivevoice.org/responsivevoice.js"></script>
```

Comment: Yes but how do I insert this is an order into the current code?

Comment: I don't know what you're doing with the rest of the code - if you're looking for how to prompt someone's name and then have it be spoken using the library, replace the whole HTML with the snippet above.

Comment: http://www.eves.website/second-original.html

Comment: After the two alerts, I am placing the prompt there, or at least im trying to

Comment: I don't see anything about "Is something here with me?" in your question (which appears to have two HTML documents + scripts combined into one for some reason?). But if you want to run that prompt and speak code after the 'Is something here with me?' alert, then just paste my JS above right after the alert, and add the library to your HTML.

Comment: I seems to only be playing first, rather than after the two alerts

Comment: Sounds like you pasted the code in the wrong place. Put it after the alerts, not before.

Comment: And just like that, I'm an idiot. THANK YOU!! ITS WOrking!!!